# String Replace in C#

Tags: c#, string

How to replace the first "AA" with "XQ" in the following strings

```
"AA1"
"AAAA1"
"AAQQ1"
"AAAAX1"
```

So the out put will be like

```
"XQ1"
"XQAA1" 
"XQQQ1"
"XQAAX1"
```

i don not know how to do this. Can any one help me to do this?